# Git svn clone not working using a SVN repository

Tags: git, repository, git-svn

In this way I can clone a SVN repository:

```
svn co svn+ssh://<username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name> /var/www/<repository_name>
```

It starts to create the expected files under `/var/www/<repository_name>`

I've installed the git svn package, and I tried to clone this SVN repository using GIT:

```
git svn clone svn+ssh://<username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name> /var/www/<repository_name>
```

It gives the following error message and it doesn't download anything:

```
svn-remote.svn.url already set: ssh://<username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name>
wanted to set to: <username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name>
```

I've also tried:

```
git svn clone <username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name> /var/www/<repository_name>
```

Which gives the same error message:

```
svn-remote.svn.url already set: ssh://<username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name>
wanted to set to: <username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name>
```

Also tried:

```
git svn clone ssh://<username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name> /var/www/<repository_name>
```

And it gives the following error message:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/<repository_name>/.git/
Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unrecognized URL scheme for  'ssh://<username>@<url>/lib/svn/<repository_name>' at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 2299
```

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried cloning to a different directory?

Comment: What version of Git are you using?  And on which OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem was related to permissions in the folder, I've tried git svn clone in another folder in my Home directory instead of `/var/www` and it worked like a charm.

Here the complete command I've used:

```
git svn clone svn+ssh://<svn_username>@<url>/var/lib/svn/<repository_name> /home/<my_user>/<repository_name>/
```

Answer (score 1):

I also used `git svn clone -s` to get the svn commit comments too.

Answer (score 0):

I also got these issues but by not specifiying a target directory:

```
sudo git svn clone svn+ssh://<username>@<host>.net/var/svn/<project>
```

Should be simply:

```
sudo git svn clone svn+ssh://<username>@<host>.net/var/svn/<project> .
```